# SonataUserBundle and Symfony 3.4

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I have a question whichone version should I use?
I started with Symfony 3.4 LTS which requires FOSUserBundle ^2.0. To use SonataUserBundle with FOSUserBundle I need to use ^4.0. In 4.0 there's no user profile things. I need to implement them all or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only one way to use SonataUserBundle of version 4.x-dev but... with special commit reference (3dd68a6aae95cffe6a4275d68c27d2766d8b93f7) and FosUserBundle of version 2.0.1. 
I know for sure, that this works for Symfony 3.3.2

Here is example of composer.json and composer.lock:

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {

    ...

    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v2.0.1",

    ...

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.18.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.1.4",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "4.x-dev",

    ...

    "symfony/symfony": "^3.3.2",

    ...

},
```

**Compose.lock (sonata user bundle part)**

```
 {
        "name": "sonata-project/user-bundle",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle.git",
            "reference": "3dd68a6aae95cffe6a4275d68c27d2766d8b93f7"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/zipball/3dd68a6aae95cffe6a4275d68c27d2766d8b93f7",
            "reference": "3dd68a6aae95cffe6a4275d68c27d2766d8b93f7",
            "shasum": ""
        },
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To use SonataUserBundle 4.x with Symfony 3.4 (and more specifically PHP 5.6/7.0), you can use `"runroom/sonata-user": "4.x-dev"` (see https://github.com/Runroom/SonataUserBundle), which is a fork of one of Sonata's team member to restore PHP 5.6/7.0 compatibility for SonataUserBundle.